# Result set in postgresql stored procedure llike java

Tags: java, postgresql, stored-procedures, cursor, fetch

hi is there any way to do the following java code in postgresql stored procedure

```
String sqlQuery = "SELECT uid, name, duration from EVENTS";

    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sqlQuery);

    while (rs.next()) {
       String name = rs.getString(2);
     }
```

i need the same in the postgresql stored procedure?

Comment: What does your Java code do? It just scrolls throug the result set (as I see). Do you want to do something with every record?

Answer (score 1):

Per the [PL/PgSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING) you use a `LOOP` over a query for that.

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
    myresult record;
BEGIN
    FOR myresult IN SELECT uid, name, duration FROM events
    LOOP
        RAISE NOTICE 'Name is %',myresult.name;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

However, use of loops is very often a sign you're just not using SQL properly. It's highly likely that proper use of `WITH` queries (common table expressions) and a bit of thought will get you a pure SQL solution that'll generally perform a LOT better.

In future, please give your PostgreSQL version and explain a little about what you're actually trying to accomplish. The code you show is completely useless, it does nothing. So it's obviously not what you really want to do, but you've told us nothing about that. Quite often the solution you *think* you need (looping, say) isn't the solution you really need.